# Find an equivalence relation E on N such that there are infinitely many equivalence classes and each of which has exactly 2017 elements.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find an equivalence relation E on N such that there are infinitely many E-equivalence classes and each of which has exactly 2017 elements.

I am having trouble finding an example, please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$aRb$ if and only $a /2017 = b/2017$ using integer arithmetic. i.e. round down